# Integrate qt project with autotool

Tags: autotools

Can any one give me a step by step instruction to integrate a QT project with autotool project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `configure.ac`:

   ```
   PKG_CHECK_MODULES(QT4, [QtCore QtGui >= 4.4.0], [
     AC_PATH_PROGS(MOC, [moc-qt4 moc], moc,`eval $PKG_CONFIG --variable=exec_prefix QtCore`/bin)
     AC_PATH_PROG(RCC, rcc, rcc,`eval $PKG_CONFIG --variable=exec_prefix QtCore`/bin)
     AC_PATH_PROGS(UIC, [uic-qt4 uic], uic,`eval $PKG_CONFIG --variable=exec_prefix QtCore`/bin)
   ], [
     AC_MSG_ERROR([Qt 4 library not found])
   ])
   ```
2. `Makefile.am`:

   ```
   application_CPPFLAGS += $(QT4_CFLAGS)
   application_LDFLAGS  += $(QT4_LIBS)
   ```

These projects uses autotools and Qt:

- [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)
- [Logread](http://logread.net/)