# How to use gnu autotool to build a qt project

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

**Solved**
I finally compile the program with the following setting.


I am new to autotool and I want to build a qt project by autotool.


**Project structure**
root/bootstrap
root/configure.ac
root/Makefile.am
root/src/
----root/src/firsttry.cpp
----root/src/firsttry.h
----root/src/Makefile.am

`root/src/firsttry.cpp`

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);

     QLabel *label = new QLabel("Hello!World! Orz...");
     label->setWindowTitle("First Qt!");
     label->resize(200, 50);
     label->show();

     return app.exec();
}
```

`root/src/Makefile.am`

... Add at the bottom

```
# qt project stuff
moc-%.cc: %.h
    @MOC@ -o$@ $(DEFS) $(DEFAULT_INCLUDES) $(INCLUDES) $(AM_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(MOC_CPPFLAGS) $<

ui-%.h: %.ui
    @UIC@ -o $@ $<

qrc-%.cc: %.qrc
    @RCC@ -o $@ $<
```

`root/configure.ac`
Added inside configure.ac file

```
# Check for Qt libraries
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(QT, [QtCore, QtGui, QtNetwork], [], [AC_MSG_ERROR([Qt libraries are required.])])

# Retrieve Qt compilation and linker flags
CPPFLAGS="`$PKG_CONFIG --cflags-only-I QtCore QtGui QtNetwork` $CPPFLAGS"
LDFLAGS="`$PKG_CONFIG --libs-only-L QtCore QtGui QtNetwork` $LDFLAGS"
LIBS="`$PKG_CONFIG --libs-only-l QtCore QtGui QtNetwork` $LIBS"

if ! `$PKG_CONFIG --atleast-version=4.6.0 QtCore`; then
   AC_MSG_ERROR([Qt >= 4.6.0 is required.])
fi

AC_CHECK_PROGS(MOC, [moc-qt5 moc-qt4 moc])
AC_CHECK_PROGS(UIC, [uic-qt5 uic-qt4 uic])
AC_CHECK_PROGS(RCC, [rcc])
 if test -z "$MOC" || test -z "$UIC" || test -z "$RCC"; then
   AC_MSG_ERROR([Qt utility programs moc, uic, and rcc are required.])
fi
```

I make this project from these references.

- [Qt hello world](http://openhome.cc/Gossip/Qt4Gossip/FirstQt.html)
- [Autotool short tutorial](https://www.gc3.uzh.ch/blog/Autotools_tutorial/)
- [Qt project build by autotool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178511/integrate-qt-project-with-autotool)

**Problem I have**
I got `<QApplication> is undefined` when I compiled the program.
Can any one give me a step-by-step tutorial?

Comment: Why do not use general qt build process qmake - make? do not forget to add to your .pro file `QT += core gui`

Comment: Anyway check build configuration that qt libraries available to linker (-L /path/ ) and added ( -lQtGui ) to compile command.

Comment: I'd consider using CMake or QMake instead of learning autotools in 2016...

Comment: @oklas It is because I have an old project which is started from autotools and I want to add an UI to it ~"~

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld this is also a question I want to ask, since I saw some projects are using autotool, I wanted to understand how they build up, so I am learning autotool. But I found that it is not easy to learn, and I am wondering is there a way to build a project in an easier way. ~"~ So CMake or QMake is the way to go?

Comment: I'd recommend CMake for anything more complex and/or if you need configure checks.

Comment: I've done [an old project using QT4](https://github.com/jmlemetayer/apm). The main difference is that I dont set `CPPFLAGS` globaly but by using `apmd_CPPFLAGS += $(QT4_CFLAGS)`. You can also check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178511/integrate-qt-project-with-autotool). *Note that both examples are using the `QT4` module and not the `QT` module*.

Comment: @jml thx, I have used it. btw, have you tried to build a qt project with .ui file? Under autotool? I have tried this `http://omg-it.works/qt-with-gnu-autotools/`, but it does not working

Comment: Nop sorry. I only did this project without UI (It was a webUI managed by [EXTjs](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/)).

Comment: It's a mistake to override those flags. Use something like `QT_CPPFLAGS` with `AC_SUBST`, and use that variable in `Makefile.am`.

Answer (score 0):

pkg-config isn't the best tool for this, there is a contrib M4 macro for Qt5+
https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_have_qt.html

Then in your Makefile.am:

```
QT_CXXFLAGS = @QT_CXXFLAGS@
QT_LIBS     = @QT_LIBS@
MOC         = @QT_MOC@
UIC         = @QT_UIC@
RCC         = @QT_RCC@

.hpp_moc.cpp:
    $(MOC) -o$@ $(DEFS) $(DEFAULT_INCLUDES) $(INCLUDES) $(CPPFLAGS) $(QT_CXXFLAGS) $<

ui_qprojectm_mainwindow.h: qprojectm_mainwindow.ui
    $(UIC) -o $@ $<

ui_qpreseteditordialog.h: qpreseteditordialog.ui
    $(UIC) -o $@ $<

ui_qprojectmconfigdialog.h: qprojectmconfigdialog.ui
    $(UIC) -o $@ $<

application_qrc.cpp: application.qrc
    $(RCC) -o $@ $<
```

And add `$(QT_CXXFLAGS)` to your `CFLAGS` and `$(QT_LIBS)` to your `LDFLAGS`